# crystal report problem

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-12

i am working on crystal reports in asp.net using c#.
i am using reportdocument object rpt for load crystal report.
i am using following code

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ServerName = @"servername";
connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "databasename";
connectionInfo.UserID = "userid";
connectionInfo.Password = "password";
//connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;

// Assign to all tables used by the report
Tables tables = rpt.Database.Tables;

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
{
    TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
    tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
}
```

here i set database login detail. Now problem is that when i run it then it requires database login information on browser.

Comment: i have this problem any one know the solutions?. pls give!.

Comment: Does the report contains a subreport?

Answer (score 0):

1. check whether all the connection details are correct
2. Try adding connection after setting report source

these might solve the issues